# Is there a way to work behind the scenes to prevent ANR from taking long work in Android?

Tags: android, background, android-service, android-room

While creating a calendar app, we are putting the ability to add events to users. If the user adds a schedule, the schedule is added from the same day to December 31, 2100. I am using `Room` Database. Here's how I tried:

```
fun add() {
    val today = Calendar.getInstance()
    val next = today.clone() as Calendar
    next.time = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd", Locale.getDefault()).parse("2100/12/31")

    CoroutineScrop(Dispatchers.Default).lanch {
        while (today.timeInMillis <= next.timeInMillis) {
            ... insert code

            today.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
        }
    }
}
```

However, even with `CoroutineScope` as above, it took quite a long time for the mobile screen to freeze for about 15 seconds. So, this time, I implemented Service so that it can work in the background.

```
class AddService: Service() {
    ...

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

        add()

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }
}
```

However, this also took a long time. In fact, I don't think it will take less time to put in a daily schedule from May 20, 2021 to December 31, 2100. At least, I want to implement the UI displayed on the screen so that it is not uncomfortable to the user. How can I implement code that keeps working in the background without affecting the UI?

**[EDIT]**

```
fun add() {
    val today = Calendar.getInstance()
    val next = today.clone() as Calendar
    next.time = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd", Locale.getDefault()).parse("2100/12/31")

    CoroutineScrop(Dispatchers.Default).lanch {
        while (today.timeInMillis <= next.timeInMillis) {
            val data = MyData(today.timeInMillis)
            MyRoomDatabase.getInstance(this@MainActivity).getDataDao().insert(data)

            today.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why is your UI freezing ? doesn't sound right

Comment: Why is it not right? Are you saying that ```CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)``` doesn't affect the ```Main Thread```?? However, in actual implementation, all buttons stop functioning when saving, the screen turns black for about 15 seconds, and then works normally. I'll edit it with the actual code attached.

Comment: Not going solve the UI issue but I'd suggest only getting the dao once before the while loop and running the loop inside a transaction see https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase#runInTransaction(java.util.concurrent.Callable%3CV%3E). run as is each insert is a transaction and incurs the overheads of writing to disk, run inside a single transaction only a single disk write is required. This could significantly reduce the time taken for all the inserts.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to avoid ANR is to make use of Thread.
You can see about usage of thread in detail in the following:
https://developer.android.com/guide/background/threading?hl=en